# how to include multiple html files from www folder in one page locally phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have multiple html files which I want to append them into different dynamic DIVs of default.html. I have done it using ajax jquery. But as per apple requirement documents, I should not be downloading any code, so is there any way i can access these html files from www folder locally packaged in phonegap build.

kindly help please...

Answer (score 0):

You would simply include the HTML files in the with the other assets of your application and load them locally using relative URLs when you need them.  You could also consider using a templating engine such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) if you need to inject dynamic data into placeholders in your HTML at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Simon Thank you for the response. 
Previously I was trying to load it with absolute path but that was not the right way to do it, so I used following line of code and it worked like a charm.

```
$.get('js/a.html').done(function(resultHTML){
    //some code
})
```

I also had to introduce base path to the application for all other ajax requests to be routed to server, therefore had to tweak ajaxSetup for server side requests.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, options) {
        var pathOrURL = options.url;
        var _parts = pathOrURL.split("."); 
        var pathExtension = _parts[_parts.length-1] || ''; //to get extension if any
        if(pathExtension !="js" && pathExtension !="css" && pathExtension != "html")
        {
            if (!(new RegExp('^(http(s)?[:]//)','i')).test(pathOrURL)) { // to check if it is relative or absolute path
                 options.url = baseUrl + options.url
            }
        }
    });
```

Its already a well cooked application and at this stage I cannot introduce any template engine.